# Compatibiliad para filter opacity en Explorer y en Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo una pagina web que va sobre Php en la que se muestra una imagen de fondo y que tiene una propiedad que es:

> filter:alpha(opacity=60)

Esta pagina funciona bien cuando se lanza desde el Internet Explorer, el problema viene al lanzarlo desde un navegador Edge, que no sale porque en Edge por lo que he visto hay que ponerlo asi:

> filter:opacity(60%)

La necesidad que tengo es que tiene que mantenerse la compatibilidad en ambos navegadores y no se como hacer para que en funcion de si es Explorer o Edge se aplique un codigo u otro.
Gracias por la ayuda,

Comment: Puedes usar simplemente `opacity: 0.6` y funcionara en IE también. En otros casos puedes usar las dos propiedades y los navegadores (en general) usarán una y la otra la obviarán

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que debes es detectar el caso en que el usuario utilize Edge puedes utilizar el siguiente script al cargar tu pagina...

`this.navigator.userAgent;`

El valor devuelto por este, contiene información sobre el nombre, la versión y plataforma del navegador...  [Navigator userAgent](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

luego con una Regex y condicionales puedes saber cual de los navegadores que te interesan esta utilizando el usuario y en dependecia utilizar una hoja de estilo diferente o un atributo especifico para un elemento..

```js
console.log(this.navigator.userAgent);

if (/MSIE 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   // Usuario utilizando internet explorer 10
   window.alert('IE10');
}

if (/MSIE 9/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // Usuario utilizando internet explorer 9 or 11
    window.alert('IE 9 o 11');
}

if (/Edge\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   // Usuario utilizando Microsoft Edge
   window.alert('Microsoft Edge');
}
```

en esta pagina [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) puedes ver los strings que te estara regresando para cada navegador y los cambios que se hagan para estos..